# Managing multiple FTP accounts

Tags: linux, ftp, file-sharing, upload

I have a Linux (opensuse 11) webserver with plesk (9.5) and I have the challange for managing multiple ftp accounts for data exchange with customers.

What I would like to have is setup easy an account and a folder so that customer could upload their files.
And preferable or guys have a central login which can access all folders but customer can not sneak into others...

Easy and fast is important. Has anyone a script or app or idea how to manage thinks like this?
Or how are you guys doing things like this...

Comment: Without Plesk !

Comment: do not need plesk want to mention it in case there is an easy way to do it with plesk. I am totally open..

Answer (score 0):

Each customer account gets `chroot`ed to `/srv/ftp/<customer>`; your staff all go into a group called `ftpadmins` then `setfacl -m d:g:ftpadmins:rwx /srv/ftp`, and you can either `chroot` them to `/srv/ftp` or just let them roam free.  I have no idea how to do this with Plesk; I'd chew my own testicles off before I'd deal with that thing ever again.

Comment: Painful, Least Effective Server Konfiguration.